# Creating a specific mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have to create a function where for each customer i will find the year and month where he had the most rents.
As for now I've got this done:

```
Select CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, count(distinct RENT_ID_PK) as total 
from t_rent
inner join t_customer on t_customer.CUSTOMER_ID_PK=t_rent.CUSTOMER_ID 
group by CUSTOMER_ID 
order by total desc;
```

To be honest got no idea how to move forward.
Any tips?

@edit

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`t_rent` (
  `RENT_ID_PK` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CAR_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `STARTING_DATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `FINISH_DATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `COMPANY_ID_START` INT NOT NULL,
  `COMPANY_ID_FINISH` INT NOT NULL,
  `RENT_COST` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RENT_ID_PK`));

CREATE TABLE `database`.`t_customer` (
  `CUSTOMER_ID_PK` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `E_MAIL` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PHONE_NO` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PERSONAL_NO` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CREDIT_CARD_NO` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ADRESS` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID_PK`));
```

Comment: It sounds like homework, just the tip: show table structure.

Comment: @AlexBarker not exactly ;) anyway can i just post the create table code for both tables? It's my first post, not sure how to use all the stuff in here

Comment: Yes, please add the create table statements to your original post.

Comment: @AlexBarker done

Comment: What in t_rent would indicate the year and month rent received?

Comment: @P.Salmon Starting_Date and Finish_date

Comment: I'm not clear how you would get a specific year and month from 2 dates which look like a date range.

Comment: @P.Salmon I suppose that I should use either only the Start_date or if it possible when there is lets say a 5 month rent range than each of the month should be counted as 1 rent.